# Why isn't this call to a template ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction

I declare two templates, the first converts the argument `x` from type `T` to type `U` and the second from type `U` to type `T`. If I call `cast` with 10, the compiler does not complain. I think both meet the requirements to be used and therefore there should be ambiguity, is that true? This code prints 10.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
U cast(T x) {
    return static_cast<U>(x);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
T cast(U x) {
    return static_cast<T>(x);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << cast<int,float>(10) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If you change your code to `cast<int,float>(10.0f)` the second overload would be called. And if you changed it to `cast<int,float>(10.0)` the call would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use `cast<int, float>`, both templates are considered.

```
template<typename T=int,typename U=float>
U cast(T x);
template<typename T=int,typename U=float>
T cast(U x);
```

we then substitute:

```
template<typename T=int,typename U=float>
float cast(int x);
template<typename T=int,typename U=float>
int cast(float x);
```

at this point, there are no types to deduce.  So we go to overload resolution.

In one case, we can take an `int` and convert to `float` when *calling* cast, and in the other we take a `int` and convert to `int` when *calling* cast.  Note I'm not looking at all into the *body* of cast; the body is not relevant to overload resolution.

The second non-conversion (at the point of call) is a better match, so that overload is chosen.

If you did this:

```
std::cout << cast<int>(10) << "\n";
```

things get more interesting:

```
template<typename T=int,typename U=?>
U cast(T x);
template<typename T=int,typename U=?>
T cast(U x);
```

for the first one, we cannot deduce `U`.  For the second one we can.

```
template<typename T=int,typename U=?>
U cast(int x);
template<typename T=int,typename U=int>
int cast(int x);
```

so here we have one viable overload, and it is used.

Comment: what OP's code actually does is convert from int to float (verified in assembler), so what non-conversion?

Comment: @jakub_d In the overload resolution of the argument.  The body of a function does not change which function is called.

Answer (score 2):

The instantiation is not ambiguous because the function argument exactly matches the first template parameter: the literal `10` is an `int`, which is also explicitly specified for the first template type.

You can make the instantiation ambiguous when the argument type does not match the explicitly specified types (thus, a conversion is necessary), e.g.

```
// error: call of overloaded 'cast<int, float>(unsigned int)' is ambiguous
std::cout << cast<int,float>(10u) << "\n";
```